Python re.sub () replace content but replacement contains special characters
I'm working on auto replacing contents in a file, the re.search() are successfully got the new_content, but it contains special characters and when I want to use re.sub() it shows :
error: invalid group reference 3 at position 85 (line 2, column 8)
I also tried using re.escape(), it will cause new_content unusable even it can replace successfully.
Here is my code :
import re
pattern = r'const\s+uint8_t\s+u8g2_custom_font\[\d+\] U8G2_FONT_SECTION.+?";\s'

with open('u8g2_custom_font.c', 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()

new_content = re.search(pattern, content, flags=re.DOTALL).group(0)

with open('u8g2_fonts.c', 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()


modified_content = re.sub(pattern, new_content, content, flags=re.DOTALL)

and here is the new_content :
const uint8_t u8g2_custom_font[1242] U8G2_FONT_SECTION("u8g2_custom_font") = 
  ";\0\3\2\5\5\3\5\6\20\20\0\376\16\376\13\377\0\0\1#\1\362\12 \20\322\301H\372\235\244"
  "s\322i\351 )i\16\245\203\244\244\71\64(\261\316I\347\244\223\222~ \6\0\320\243\0(\14\203"
  "\375\241J\242$\352-\312\2)\15\203\371\241\310\242,\352%J\42\0-\7$\230\242\30\2.\7B"
  "\34\242\30\2/\14F\25\242-V\303\64\254\246\0\60\21F\25\242\322\242$\324\246D\211\66\61\211\62"
  "\11\61\13E\31\242\312\244$\354\323 \62\17F\25\242\31\222PL\63-\254\246\303\0\63\20F\25\242"
  "\31\222PL\243\71\25\305dH\0\64\20F\25\242\14\265$\252dI\226\14cZ\1\71\16F\25\242"
  "\31\222\320\230\14jc\64\1:\10\342<\242\30\342!C\15F\25\242\31\222\320\332QL\206\4F\14"
  "F\25\242\70\244\325AI\273\2H\13F\25\242\10\35\207A\364\30L\11F\25\242H\373\353\60P\15"
  "F\25\242\30\224\320\70,iW\0R\20F\25\242\30\224\320\70,Q-\311\222P\14T\12G\25\242"
  "\70dq\177\3Y\16G\25\242H\325$\213\262J\32w\3_\7'\364\241\70\4a\16\6\25\242\31"
  "\222\60M\206\321\246,\1c\15\6\25\242\31\222P\355\230\14\11\0d\14f\25\242mY\264\321\233\262"
  "\4e\17\6\25\242\31\222P\34\6\265\230\14\11\0h\13f\25\242H[\26M\364\61i\13e\31\242"
  "\12sD\354\323 j\14\245\325\241\254#b\37\245H\2m\22\7\25\242X\224(\222\42)\222\42)"
  "\222\42\251\0n\12\6\25\242H\26M\364\61o\14\6\25\242\31\222\320\307dH\0p\16F\325\241H"
  "\26Mt\334\224%M\1r\13\6\25\242H\26MT\273\2s\14\6\25\242\31\222PvL\206\4u"
  "\12\6\25\242\10\375\246,\1w\21\7\25\242H\245H\212\244H\212\244H\252X\0\334\15\306\25\242\211"
  "\332\341\320\77&C\2\0\0\0\4\377\377 &\12G\24\242\210\42\251\0\60\253\31\252\371\301\314\261\34"
  "\12\303A\31\264\260[\330\226FY\22\245:\222\1\60\267\26j\35\302\321\261\234\244cq\216\344H\216"
  "\344H\30\311:\0\60\350\26i\35\302\34\216\71\222#\341\20m\71\222#\71\222\16\321\30\60\353\30k"
  "\31\302\315\263<\312\243<\312JY\251V\312*Y\250\245!\0N\12\37\357\361\301\316\361\34\317\361\34"
  "\317\361\34\37\206\34\311\361\34\317\361\34\317\361\34\317\221\341\3W\30)\15\326\301\370\240\246\312pQS"
  "i\30\42\251I\32\206Hj\222\206!R\263D\31.z\246\14\27)\314\264H\33\36\4[P\37\357"
  "\321\301\31\336\341\34\316\341\34\325\341|\370\236\343\71\236\343\71\236\343\71\232\344p\216\0[\244\42\357\361"
  "\301\316)\71\62<(\71\252\243\331p\320s\70\315\207;V\307rh\70\350P\216\347\303\7e\234."
  "\17\322\301\314\343\60J\223\60\11\263J\226\206Q\62H\345\64\211\323$\33\206p\14\207\60\251\206I\24"
  "fQ\61\312\362\60\311\323\34\211\0h\177*\17\322\301\313\361l\30\302,\15\263aH\206%\15\263a"
  "\310tx\7\223\312\60DI\261\24\347\321p\213\363\70\217\363\70\4i\5/\17\322\301\212\363\70\317\206"
  "AK\223p\220\262\64K\303h\70$;\222)\311\20U\262\250%\213\212YT\314\206(\314\241\60O"
  "\302\34\311\0j\2-\17\322\301\12\323\254\34e\203\324\222%\321\20e\311\224\15RK\226D\203\222%"
  "C\226\14b\236\17_\223:\324\254e\222\232\352\71\0mt*\17\322\301\317\322\260\32\305a\222Ur"
  "$\256\244\265\70J+\271\224\15C\264\245a\226\206Y\32fi\230\15C\216\244\21\0v\204%\15\326"
  "\301J\343\264\34\16\323\60&\241\230\204V\61\312\206!\213\304,\22c\61\26\343a\210\305,\311\301\10"
  "}\332\62\17\322\301Ks$\314\221p\30\262$J\243\322\60$C\226\206\331\60dy\32\245\322\260,"
  "J\232%u\250\22%\245\226nQ\22FI\226C)\0\215\357,\17\322\301\207\342A\213\263l\310J"
  "YK\343 \346i\22\207Y\232\245J\62\15Z\22f\225\60\253\204Ye\312\242u\320\261\22\0\226}"
  "/\356\325\301\30\244a\311\242\60\211\262a\211\262\60)\16K\224cQ\64\334\242\70\213\206AK\242$"
  "YJ\25%\214\42\65\312\364\244\71\213\0\226\373(\17\322\301\32\16:\224#\303\203\222\306\322\222,\71"
  "\222cK\262\223\207\203\330\70\34\304\306\341\240Cq\36\347\310\60\4\234\345#\15\326\301\315\301\34\33\216"
  "y\70\34\363p\70\346\350p\220rt\70hQK\324Rj\321\221:\30\1\0";

I would like to replace with the the new_content and wont cause it unusable.

All the things like \0 and \2 are back-references to capture groups. You need to escape them as \\0 and \\2 to make the backslashes literal.

Is there any function in re to auto escape these kind of back slash or I have to manually add it. I had tried re.escape(), it will cause the result unusable. Thank you for your reply!

I'm not sure why re.escape() didn't work for you.

Can you add sample input and desired output to the question?

If I apply re.escape(), It will be like :
'print(re.escape(new_content))'
"""
const\ uint8_t\ u8g2_custom_font[1242]\ U8G2_FONT_SECTION("u8g2_custom_font")\ =\ 
\ \ ";\0\3\2\5\5\3\5\6\20\20\0\376\16\376\13\377\0\0\1#\1\362\12\ \20\322\301H\372\235\244"
.......
"""

The reason re.escape doesn't work is in the documentation:

re.escape(pattern)
...
This function must not be used for the replacement string in sub() and subn(), only backslashes should be escaped.

Use:
modified_content = re.sub(pattern, new_content.replace('\\', r'\\'), content, flags=re.DOTALL)
#                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Here is a simplified example:
import re

pattern = r'const\s+uint8_t\s+font\[\d+\] FONT.+?";\s'

new_content = r'''const uint8_t font[123] FONT("u8g2_custom_font") =
  "\1\2\3\4";
'''

content = r'''
double abc;
const uint8_t font[123] FONT("u8g2_custom_font") = "abcd";
int x = 123;
'''

# reproduces OP exception
try:
    print(re.sub(pattern, new_content, content, flags=re.DOTALL))
except re.error as e:
    print(e)

# incorrect result using re.escape
print(re.sub(pattern, re.escape(new_content), content, flags=re.DOTALL))

# correct result escaping backslashes only
print(re.sub(pattern, new_content.replace('\\', r'\\'), content, flags=re.DOTALL))

Output:
invalid group reference 1 at position 55 (line 2, column 5)

double abc;
const\ uint8_t\ font\[123\]\ FONT\("u8g2_custom_font"\)\ =\
\ \ "\1\2\3\4";\
int x = 123;


double abc;
const uint8_t font[123] FONT("u8g2_custom_font") =
  "\1\2\3\4";
int x = 123;

